# crystal report viewer how to hide parameters panel prompt

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, report

The parameter prompt is still coming as a pop up, I want to avoid that
in crystal report viewer how to hide parameters panel prompt

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to hide the entire dialog box, including the input fields, or are you only wanting to hide the text in the title bar?  The question is worded in a way that makes me think its the entire dialog box you want to hide, but the image has a box drawn around the text that makes me question that, so if you could clarify that would be helpful.

Comment: want to hide the entire dialog box  including the input fields

Comment: Crystal Reports doesn't have a way to do this from the report's designer.  Any time the report is refreshed, it will prompt the user to enter new parameters.  You may be able to do something in your C# application though.  Check out this link from the SAP forums.

https://answers.sap.com/questions/9966654/want-to-disable-the-parameter-prompt-in-crystal-re.html